# bypass folder permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to give access to `c`,where 'a' is restricted.
The reason for that is that I would like to share a few files by symlinks in `a`.

```
a              <- drwx------
└ b            <- drwxr-xr-x
  └ c          <- drwxr-xr-x


ln -s ../a/b/c/some_files ../a/
```

I understood that I need all `a`,`b` and `c` **`+x`** and `c` **`+r`** but it doesn't work that way. Now a is drwx--x--x

How do I achieve my goal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your intents and purposes, what you are attempting to do isn't possible with the current permissions and ownership. It can be done with a bind mount but then the symlink wouldn't work.

As you already know, `a` can't be traversed by anyone but the owner (and root) which means that `b` and `c` also can't be accessed by anyone else so it doesn't matter that they can already be read and traversed by everyone.

The only thing that you can to do is to either change the permissions for `a` to `755` or if you don't want to give access to everyone, create a group and add only those whom you want to have access, set it as the group for `a`, and then change the permissions for `a` to `750`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible: you need to create a **hardlink** to `a/b/c/some_files`.  And then you can remove absolutely all "`o`" permissions from the intervening directories!

BTW, it's safest to specify *absolute* paths when creating links.

#### Demo: Prep

```bash
# whoami
root

# mkdir -p /a/b/c
# touch /a/b/c/d
# chmod o= /a/
# chmod o= /a/b/
# chmod o= /a/b/c/
# ls -ld /a/
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 15 Dec 23 20:45 /a/

# ls -ld /a/b/
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 15 Dec 23 20:45 /a/b/

# ls -ld /a/b/c/
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 15 Dec 23 20:45 /a/b/c/

# ls -l /a/b/c/d
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Dec 23 20:46 /a/b/c/d

# ln -s /a/b/c/d /softlink-to-d
# ls -l /softlink-to-d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Dec 23 20:47 /softlink-to-d -> /a/b/c/d

# ln    /a/b/c/d /hardlink-to-d
# ls -l /hardlink-to-d
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 0 Dec 23 21:09 /hardlink-to-d
```

#### Demo: Proof

```bash
# su - postgres -c 'touch /a/b/c/d'
touch: cannot touch ‘/a/b/c/d’: Permission denied

# su - postgres -c 'touch /softlink-to-d'
touch: cannot touch ‘/softlink-to-d’: Permission denied

# ls -l /a/b/c/d
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 0 Dec 23 20:46 /a/b/c/d
                       ### Note, mtime still unchanged...

# su - postgres -c 'touch /hardlink-to-d'

# ls -l /a/b/c/d
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 0 Dec 23 21:13 /a/b/c/d
                       ### ...finally, mtime changed.
```